# git clone throws error with vcsrepo module puppet

Tags: linux, git, puppet

I am following the pluralsight's tutorial for puppet fundamentals by Ben Piper.
When installing the "vcsrepo" module in agents and downloading the repository the puppet agent run hangs.

Below is the excerpt from my puppet master "init.pp" file

```
I changed my puppetmaster init.pp file to use the ssh instead.


  `file { '/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa':
  ensure   =>  'present',
  }

  vcsrepo { '/var/www/html':
  ensure    => 'present',
  provider  => 'git',
  source    => 'git@github.com:wikimedia/mediawiki.git',
  user      => 'vagrant',
  revision  => 'REL1_23',
  require   => File['/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa'],

  }

  file { '/var/www/html/index.html':
  ensure   =>  'absent',
 }

 File['/var/www/html/index.html'] -> Vcsrepo['/var/www/html']`
```

It now throws the below error

`Notice: /Stage[main]/Linux/File[/info.txt]/content: content changed '{md5}dd4735ab73567a89caba62c6607e44b5' to '{md5}e30fa7cc7448a09071a0e4d33efa5986'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Vcsrepo[/var/www/html]/ensure: Creating repository from present
Error: Execution of 'git clone git@github.com:wikimedia/mediawiki.git /var/www/html' returned 1:
Error: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Vcsrepo[/var/www/html]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of 'git clone git@github.com:wikimedia/mediawiki.git /var/www/html' returned 1:`

I have shared my system's public key in github account

Answer (score 0):

**On Linux**

Execute the following in the command line before executing the Git command:

```
export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
export GIT_TRACE=1
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

**On Windows**

Execute the following in the command line before executing the Git command:

```
set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
set GIT_TRACE=1
set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

**Cause**

Error code 56 indicates a curl receive error of CURLE_RECV_ERROR which means there was some issue that prevented the data from being received during the clone process. Typically this is caused by a network setting, firewall, VPN client, or anti-virus that is terminating the connection before all data has been transferred.

**Workaround**

Switch to using SSH to perform the clone.

Comment: have you tried connecting from the terminal without using the puppet script? did you generate the key and authenticate git hub?